# export multible dataframes to multible worksheets in one csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two variables, lets say `var_1` and `var_2` and I want both to export into one csv file but in two worksheets. So at the end I would like to have "export.csv" with two worksheets, each containing a df of `var_1` oder `var_2`.

For the moment I'm using `var_1.to_csv()`, I think there must be some similar...

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the CSV file format with an Excel table. Excel tables can support multiple tabs or worksheets, but a CSV file cannot.

To get around this, you can use the `pandas.ExcelWriter()` method to save multiple dataframes to separate worksheets:

```py
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my_dataframes.xlsx')

var_1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='worksheet1')
var_2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='worksheet2')

writer.save()
```

See https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html for more information.

Comment: Well, thanks! That is a point I didn't thought about as excel shows also the worksheet-tabs for an opened csv file... but it won't work if you use it. You are completely right!